# Refactoring a list of checkboxes to be less DRY

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I had a few checkboxes that I wanted to display on the screen and I realized I was taking a very lazy approach.

Originally had something like:

```
return (
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox"/>
    <input type="checkbox"/>
    <input type="checkbox"/>
  </div>
)
```

I refactored to this, but I'm wondering if there's a better way to do it. Something seems odd about it, but I can't quite pinpoint it.
**https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-gwen-ytkvjy?file=/src/App.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const stuff = {
    item1: {
      checked: false,
      description: "#1 description"
    },
    item2: {
      checked: false,
      description: "#2 description"
    },
    item3: {
      checked: false,
      description: "#3 description"
    },
    item4: {
      checked: false,
      description: "#4 description"
    },
    item5: {
      checked: false,
      description: "#5 description"
    }
  };
  const [checkbox, setCheckbox] = useState(stuff);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      {Object.entries(checkbox).map(([key, value]) => (
        <div>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            name={key}
            checked={value.checked}
            key={key}
            onChange={(e) => {
              setCheckbox((prev) => ({
                ...prev,
                [key]: { ...value, checked: e.target.checked }
              }));
            }}
          />
          <>{value.description}</>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: looks like you want to abstract checkbox into its own component

Comment: What’s wrong with being lazy? What I’ve noticed is that usually somebody throws a monkey wrench in your nice abstraction that makes it not work so great (on the third checkbox, I want a smiley face emoji if the second checkbox has been checked). At which point you’ll either hack your abstraction to make it work for the new requirement, when it would’ve paid dividends to keep doing it the lazy way

Comment: Nothing wrong with the first approach I guess. I just wanted to try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd separate the data and the checkedness state:

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-ives-j6kh78?file=/src/App.js)

To address Adam Jenkins' comment on the original post, this also shows it's easy to change the items depending on the state.

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

function CheckboxGroup({ items, checkedIds, onChange }) {
  return (
    <>
      {items.map(({ id, label }) => (
        <label>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            checked={!!checkedIds[id]}
            key={id}
            onChange={(e) => onChange(id, e.target.checked)}
          />
          {label}
        </label>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}

const baseItems = Array(5)
  .fill(null)
  .map((_, i) => ({
    id: `item${i}`,
    label: `Description ${i + 1}`
  }));

export default function App() {
  const [checkedIds, setCheckedIds] = React.useState({});
  const handleChange = (id, checked) =>
    setCheckedIds((c) => ({ ...c, [id]: checked }));

  const numberChecked = Object.values(checkedIds).filter(Boolean).length;

  // Demonstrate changing the items when a condition occurs
  const items =
    numberChecked >= 3
      ? baseItems.map((item) => ({ ...item, label: item.label.toUpperCase() }))
      : baseItems;

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <CheckboxGroup
        items={items}
        checkedIds={checkedIds}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(checkedIds)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Yea it was the state management that seemed off in my original post. I like this a lot better.